# Finding the supply voltage, knowing the resistance and current

Tags: voltage, dc

I am learning the basics of electrotechnics. I had this task for my university that I failed doing and I want to learn how to solve it anyway. Thanks for assistance! :)

Here is the exercise task: [image: exercise task]
I assume I need to find the \$U\$. Knowing the \$I = 14 A\$ and \$R = 8 Ω\$

This is how I calculated this:

\$ U = IR_{z} \$ where \$ R_{z} = R_{123456}\$ (equivalent resistance)

\$ R_{12} = R_{1} + R_{2} = 4 Ω + 4 Ω = 8 Ω \$

\$ R_{123} = \frac{R_{12}R_{3}}{R_{12}+R_{3}} = \frac{8 Ω * 8 Ω}{8 Ω + 8 Ω} = 4 Ω\$

\$ R_{1234} = R_{123} + R_{4} = 4 Ω + 4 Ω = 8 Ω \$

\$ R_{12345} = \frac{R_{1234}R_{5}}{R_{1234}+R_{5}} = \frac{8 Ω * 8 Ω}{8 Ω + 8 Ω} = 4 Ω\$

\$ R_{123456} = R_{12345} + R_{6} = 4 Ω + 4 Ω = 8 Ω \$

\$ R_{z} = R_{123456} = 8 Ω \$

\$ U = IR_{z} = 14 A * 8 Ω = 112 V \$

Yet somehow 112 V is wrong answer. Any clues, hints? Where did I do an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculated the voltage so that the total current provided by the supply is 14 A. But not all of that current goes through the branch identified by the "I" in the schematic. So now you need to figure out what fraction of the total current is I, and scale your input voltage appropriately to get 14 A at "I".

Comment: Thanks, but no idea how to proceed any further :/ I suppose it has to do something with the Kirchoff's Law, but no clue how to proceed.

Comment: Do you know the current divider rule?

Comment: I think so. Ix =  ( Rz / Rx ) * I. But not sure how to apply that rule into such 'complicated' circuit.

Comment: Just back up the simplifications you did, one at a time.

Comment: Or if you just want to do it the brute force way, just assume a voltage source connected at the inputs, use node or mesh analysis to find *I*, then scale the source to get 14 A.

Comment: Thanks! If that doesn't take too much out of your time, would you verify if the total I of the circuit is 56 A? That way the voltage would be 56 A * 8 Ohm = 448 V.

Comment: @weno, yes, that's correct.